# Background Service stop after power saver enable and disable

Tags: android, service, android-6.0-marshmallow, intentservice, background-service

I have an application in which I perform some task in background,

So the task will perform if my background service is running

**Problem :** When I enable and disable power saver, so it close everything and stop every background services which are running. After turning off power saver the service is not getting start till I open the application.

**So how I can restart my background service when power saver off for lower version than Android.M**

***Facing issue in Android 6.0 and below.***

Myservice.java

```
public class Myservice extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I Start this service is my MainActivity.java

So I can get any kind of broadcast or notification of power saver

Comment: Idk answer but may be evernote job scheduler can fix your issue. https://github.com/evernote/android-job