# Destroying a service as soon as the app is killed

Tags: android, android-service

I need to create a service that will run as much as app will be running. I know that the most straightforward solution would be to bind service in my `Application` class but this class does not have `onDestroy` `onStop` or `onPause` methods so `unbinding` is not possible... sadly... Other approach is to bind service to my base activity (and other activities will extend that activity) and for example `onResume bind and onStop unbind` service. But then service will be always recreated... And that is not I want. Is it possible to have continuously running service and destroy it as soon as application closed? Here's the second approach (this code is in my base activity)

```
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (service == null && !isBound) {
            bindService(new Intent(this, NetworkListenerService.class), mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
    }

@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (isBound) {
            unbindService(mServiceConnection);
            isBound = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes you can easily do this

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But how can I do that?

Comment: Check my edited answer below

Comment: Can u try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46500119/background-service-stop-after-power-saver-enable-and-disable

Answer (score 1):

Set the below attribute in your service tag in the manifest file,

```
<service android:name="service" android:stopWithTask="true"/>
```

adding this will call the `ondestroy()` of the service when the task is removed.

Comment: Ok but what if I need to destroy a service not when task is removed but when app is killed?

Comment: @David in android activity cycle there is no way to determine app is been killed or normal exited. In both case onDestroy() will be called

Comment: @David then instant of using service you can use IntentService.